# WPF Checkbox selections not applying in powershell script

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am working with a WPF Powershell project (learning and incorporating relatable tasks while doing it). I have two check boxes which toggle the external senders auth on distribution groups.

I want that if you want to set it so you allow external, you tick the box, then input the group in a textbox, then click a button to then process the change. It will then display a message in a textbox saying done.

The issue I have is that the code seems to run, however no changes are made, so it's not picking up the selected checkbox nor actually processing the code. The fact it then doesn't display the message is something I can figure out when I get the first part to work.

The other checkbox allows you to set it to not receive external should it already allow it.

Below is the function I am currently trying. It seems to execute, no errors show in the visual studio debug menus.

```
function SetExternalSenderClick
{
    param($sender, $e)
    
    #Script prompts for Creds
    $PSCred = Get-Credential
    
    
    #Script connects to Exchange On-Prem
    $OnPremExSession = New-PSSession -Credential $PSCred -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://************/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
    import-pssession $OnPremExSession
    
    if ($SetExternalTrue.IsChecked){
    
    $DG = $ExternalDGNameText.text
    
    Get-DistributionGroup -identity $DG | Set-DistributionGroup -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $False
    
    #Clear the textbox before adding new results
    $DGChangesResultsText.Clear()
    
    #Append text to textbox to confrim addition
    $DGChangesResultsText.AppendText("External emails set to allow. ")
    
     }
    
    elseif ($SetExternalFalse.IsChecked){
    
    $DG1 = $ExternalDGNameText.text
    
    Get-DistributionGroup -identity $DG1 | Set-DistributionGroup -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $True
    
    #Clear the textbox before adding new results
    $DGChangesResultsText.Clear()
    
    #Append text to textbox to confrim addition
    $DGChangesResultsText.AppendText("External emails set to deny ")
    
     }
    
    Remove-PSSession $OnPremExSession
}
```

Minimal working example

```
<Window

  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>

        <Label Content="DG Names&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Height="27"/>

        <Button x:Name="SetExternalSender" Content="Set External Sender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Click="SetExternalSenderClick"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ExternalDGName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="139,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="SetExternalTrue" Content="Set External True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="SetExternalFalse" Content="Set External False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="DGChangesResultsText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="59,200,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

PS code

```
function Add-ControlVariables {
    
New-Variable -Name 'SetExternalSender' -Value $window.FindName('SetExternalSender') -Scope 1 -Force
New-Variable -Name 'ExternalDGName' -Value $window.FindName('ExternalDGName') -Scope 1 -Force
New-Variable -Name 'DGChangesResultsText' -Value $window.FindName('DGChangesResultsText') -Scope 1 -Force
}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework") | Out-Null

function Import-Xaml {
    [xml]$xaml = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\WpfWindow1.xaml
    $manager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xaml.NameTable
    $manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@x:Name='SetExternalSender']", $manager)[0].RemoveAttribute('Click')
    $xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
}

function Set-EventHandler {

    $SetExternalSender.add_Click({
        param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e)
        SetExternalSenderClick -sender $sender -e $e
    })
}
#ERROR: You need to define the x:Name attribute for this control to generate an event handler.


$window = Import-Xaml
Add-ControlVariables
Set-EventHandler

function SetExternalSenderClick
{
    param($sender, $e)

    #Script prompts for Creds
    $PSCred = Get-Credential
    
    
    #Script connects to Exchange On-Prem
    $OnPremExSession = New-PSSession -Credential $PSCred -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://************/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
    import-pssession $OnPremExSession
    
    if ($SetExternalTrue.IsChecked){
    
    $DG = $ExternalDGNameText.text
    
    Get-DistributionGroup -identity $DG | Set-DistributionGroup -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $False
    
    #Clear the textbox before adding new results
    $DGChangesResultsText.Clear()
    
    #Append text to textbox to confrim addition
    $DGChangesResultsText.AppendText("External emails set to allow. ")
    
     }
    
    elseif ($SetExternalFalse.IsChecked){
    
    $DG1 = $ExternalDGNameText.text
    
    Get-DistributionGroup -identity $DG1 | Set-DistributionGroup -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $True
    
    #Clear the textbox before adding new results
    $DGChangesResultsText.Clear()
    
    #Append text to textbox to confrim addition
    $DGChangesResultsText.AppendText("External emails set to deny ")
    
     }
    
    Remove-PSSession $OnPremExSession
}


$window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I input the DG then tick the box for allow external senders. Then hit the apply button. It prompts as it should for credentials then loads the module fine.. However no errors appear and when i check the DG the changes are not applied to it.. Yet i had no errors. SO presume the code is not getting to the stage to execute the exchange commands.

Comment: The click is called so prompts for credentials to connect to Exchange... Then i get no errors so presume its going no further. Not taking the if statements by looks of it.

Comment: So neither `$SetExternalTrue` nor `$SetExternalFalse` is actually checked or what?

Comment: So true is checked. One needs to be checked is what should happen... Seems when i check one and run the click it doesn't make the changes...

Comment: What should happen is:
1. User ticks either allow external or deny external
2. User enters the DG in the textbox
3. User clicks the button to make changes. 
4. Script then prompts for creds.
5. Script takes the checkbox which is ticked then runs the required command.
6. Script pastes message to textbox to say done. 

What happens is steps 1-4 work then nothing happens. No errors.. So presume it doesn't like the code in the if functions. 
I get not errors in the console in VS.

Comment: Try to remove the call to `Get-DistributionGroup` and make something very simply in the code.

Comment: And please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question if you need any further help.

Comment: Ok reproducible example included.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the first checkbox, remove `Checked="CheckBox_Checked"` from your XML and add this in your script in the "Add-ControlVariables" function:

`New-Variable -Name 'SetExternalTrue' -Value $window.FindName('SetExternalTrue') -Scope 1 -Force`

`New-Variable -Name 'SetExternalFalse' -Value $window.FindName('SetExternalFalse') -Scope 1 -Force`

`$SetExternalTrue.Ischecked = $true`